# Add custom Column Chart Datalabels in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, label, series, excel-charts

I have a [Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3jn1.png) object where I want to edit DataLabels of Columns from VBA code. How can I do to achive this goal?

For example: add any string or percentages next to values.

EDIT 1

This is the [Data Range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svNCr.png) where I have the info.

The following Sub creates a chart and try to edit the DataLabels of columns.

```
Sub createChart()
'PURPOSE: Create a chart (chart dimensions are required)

Dim rng As Range
Dim pChart As Object
Dim nRng, vRng, labelStr As String
Dim i As Integer

Set report_sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("REPORT")
With report_sht
    'data range for the chart
    Set rng = .Range("E16:F20")
End With

Set pChart = report_sht.Shapes.AddChart2(Style:=-1, XlChartType:=xlColumnClustered, Left:=Range("D22").Left, Top:=Range("D22").Top, Width:=645, Height:=340, NewLayout:=True)
pChart.Chart.ChartWizard Source:=rng, PlotBy:=xlColumns, SeriesLabels:=0, HasLegend:=1, Title:="Chart Title"

pChart.Name = "chartName"

With report_sht.ChartObjects("chartName").Chart
    .ClearToMatchStyle
    .ChartStyle = 209
    .Axes(xlCategory).Delete
    .Legend.Position = xlRight
    With .Axes(xlValue)
        .HasTitle = True
        .AxisTitle.Text = "Data Values"
    End With
    For Each s In .SeriesCollection
      s.Delete
    Next s
    For i = 1 To 5
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        nRng = "E" & (15 + i)
        vRng = "F" & (15 + i)
        With .SeriesCollection(i)
            .Name = report_sht.Range(nRng)
            .Values = report_sht.Range(vRng)
            labelStr = " blah blah"
            .HasDataLabels = True
            .DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange. _
              InsertAfter labelStr & Chr(13) & ""
            With .Format.Fill
                .Visible = msoTrue
                Select Case i
                    Case 1
                        'BLUE
                        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(51, 102, 204)
                    Case 2
                        'RED
                        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 80, 80)
                    Case 3
                        'ORANGE
                        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent2
                        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
                        .ForeColor.Brightness = 0.400000006
                        'What is this color in RGB?
                    Case 4
                        'GREEN
                        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80)
                    Case 5
                        'YELLOW
                        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 153)
                End Select
                .Transparency = 0
                .Solid
            End With
        End With
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

This is the [resulting Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mX9Ah.png) after executing the code. No DataLabels was edited.

EDIT 2

The [line error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cI9of.png) after try the code. Run-Time Error '-2147024809 (80070057)'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the macro recorder while making an update to your chart, then use the generated code as a starting point.

Eg: you will get something like this -

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels(3).Format.TextFrame2.TextRange. _
    InsertAfter "  blah blah" & Chr(13) & ""
```

**edit:** this line from your posted code -

```
.DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.InsertAfter labelStr & Chr(13) & ""
```

should be

```
.DataLabels(1).Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.InsertAfter labelStr & Chr(13) & ""
```

Works for me with that change.

Comment: I tried this before @TimWilliams! But without succes.

Comment: In that case it would help to update your question with the code you tried, and describe what happened when you ran that code.

Comment: I updated my question in order to clarify what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I tried your code. I'm getting "Run-Time Error '-2147024809 (80070057)' Invalid parameter" in that line.

Comment: I used your data and code and it worked for me with that one change.

Comment: I'm using Office 2016. Still getting the error. What else can I be doing wrong?

Comment: Here's my working copy - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ng-0RDY405K55KoAMp5oOpUe-dvMwa-s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams! Works perfectly. However I can't figure it out why doesn't work in my Workbook. [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=153xkZhSo1HOSoXveEpAc0LiSnAZ0MBmV) is the file.